# Improving performance of Location based search using Lucene

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene for a job search portal using .net.
Am facing some performance related issues in the following use case.
Use case is:
When doing job search, user can select job location(for exameple:Atlanta,GA) and select radial distance (say 50 miles).The time required to return job search results from Lucene is pretty high.

FYI,we are maintaining a sql server 2005 database where we store US and Canada based city,state,longitude and latitude.(contains a total of about 1 million records).

Is there anyway I can improve the performace of this location based job search?

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on how exactly you are using Lucene to do location-based searches in relation to your database? When a user searches for "Atlanta,GA", for example, how does Lucene know which cities are within 50 miles of it? Does it have to first query the database?

Comment: Thanks for ur comments.We have a .Net based distance API which takes location as input and returns nearest cities within a given radius.This collection is then given to Lucene for searching jobs.

Comment: So are you searching the Lucene index for the string "Atlanta, GA" ?  What are you indexing?  Do you index "Atlanta, GA" as one term or is it split into tokens?

Comment: I index Atlanta in a field named "city" and GA in "state" in Lucene index.

Comment: How big is your Lucene index?  Just indexing every city and state in the US and Can. would be a very small index and should be lightning fast.  What type of Query are you using to find the correct cities?

Comment: please see my comments in my answer below.
                }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you have two types of search parameters: textual and spatial.
You can probably use one type to filter the results you got from the other.
For example, for someone looking for a .NET developer job near Atlanta, GA
you could either first retrieve all the .NET developer jobs and filter for location, 
or retrieve all jobs around Atlanta and filter for .NET developer ones.
I believe the first should be faster.
You can also store the job locations directly in Lucene, and incorporate them in the search.
A rough draft is:
Indexing:
 1. When you receive a new 'wanted' ad, find its geo-location using the database.
 2. Store the location as a Lucene field in the ad's document.
Retrieval:
 1. Retrieve all jobs according to textual matches.
 2. Use geometrical calculations for finding distances between the user's place and the job location.
 3. Filter jobs according to distance.

[Lucene in Action](http://www.manning.com/hatcher2/) has an example of spatial search similar in spirit. [A second edition](http://www.manning.com/hatcher3/) is in the making. Also, check out [Sujit Pal's suggestions for spatial search with Lucene](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2008/02/spatial-search-with-lucene.html) and [Patrick O'Leary's framework](http://www.nsshutdown.com/projects/lucene/whitepaper/locallucene_v2.html). There are also [Locallucene](http://locallucene.wiki.sourceforge.net/) and [LocalSolr](http://www.gissearch.com/localsolr), but I do not know how mature they are.

Answer (score 0):

my index size is about 4 MB.Am using the following code for building query for nearest cities:

```
foreach (string city in htNearestCities.Keys)
                {
                    cityStateQuery = new BooleanQuery();
                    queryCity = queryParserCity.Parse("\"" + city + "\"");
                    queryState = queryParserState.Parse("\"" + ((string[])htNearestCities[city])[1] + "\"");
                    cityStateQuery.Add(queryCity, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST); 
                    cityStateQuery.Add(queryState, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

                    findLocationQuery.Add(cityStateQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
                    }
```

Comment: 4MB?  Lucene's a bit overkill for such a small data set.

Answer (score 0):

You may ultimately want to have lucene handle the spatial search by indexing [tiles](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/).  But if you're certain the lucene query is slow, not the finding of the cities, then start by indexing the state and city together.  Much like indexing multiple columns in a relational database: a 'state:city' field with values like 'GA:Atlanta'.  Then the intersection isn't done at query time.